# WPF RichTextBox font spacing inconsistency

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I found the WPF RichTextBox that renders FlowDocument is not WYSIWYG.

Screenshot below shows the Editor (left) has reduced spacing compared to its rendered PDF output (right).

[image: RTB vs PDF]

The xaml for this document.

```
<ns0:FlowDocument xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xps/2005/06"
                  Background="#FFFFFFFF" ColumnWidth="816" PageWidth="816" PageHeight="1056"
                  AllowDrop="True" NumberSubstitution.CultureSource="User">
  <ns0:FlowDocument.Blocks>
    <ns0:Paragraph>
      <ns0:Paragraph.Inlines>
        <ns0:Run Text="72" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="72" />
      </ns0:Paragraph.Inlines>
    </ns0:Paragraph>
    <ns0:Paragraph>
      <ns0:Paragraph.Inlines>
        <ns0:Run Text="48" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="48" />
      </ns0:Paragraph.Inlines>
    </ns0:Paragraph>
    <ns0:Paragraph>
      <ns0:Paragraph.Inlines>
        <ns0:Run Text="20" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="20" />
      </ns0:Paragraph.Inlines>
    </ns0:Paragraph>
    <ns0:Paragraph>
      <ns0:Paragraph.Inlines>
        <ns0:Run Text="12" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="12" />
      </ns0:Paragraph.Inlines>
    </ns0:Paragraph>
    <ns0:Paragraph>
      <ns0:Paragraph.Inlines>
        <ns0:Run Text="08" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="8" />
      </ns0:Paragraph.Inlines>
    </ns0:Paragraph>
  </ns0:FlowDocument.Blocks>
</ns0:FlowDocument>
```

Do you have a workaround to address this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want page fidelity then FlowDocument is the wrong tool.
A FlowDocuement is just that - Flow - it knows no page specification.
For page fidelity use [FixedDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.fixeddocument(v=vs.110).aspx).

On screen PDF next to a Microsoft Word will also not necessarily have the same spacing.
Those two images also don't a have the same text height.
Reader has a zoom.
Why would you even expect those two images to be the same?